# Find the supremum and the infimum of $A$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I am attending a course in calculus and need to find the supremum and infimum of the set $A$.

$$A := \left\{2(-1)^{n+1} + (-1)^{\frac12(n(n+1))} \left(2 + \frac 3n\right): n \in \Bbb N\right\}$$

I am puzzled as to how to treat this set. I tried computing the limit for $n \to 1$ and $n\to\infty$; with poor success.

Comment: What have you already tried? Have you tried working out the members of $A$ corresponding to $n=1,2,3,\dots$? Formally trying to find a limit doesn't really make much sense as suprema and infima are a more primitive concept than limits. Also, a limit wouldn't necessarily tell you what the supremum or infimum is. This doesn't work for say $B=\{1+\frac{(-1)^n}n\,:\,n=1,2,3,\dots\}$

Comment: Yes, I see now how unuseful the limit is. I have tried out values, say {1,2,3,4,5} in order to see what values A takes according to the exponent, since (-1) is positive for even exponents and negative for odd exponents. I used wolfram alpha and saw the graph. The main issue is that I do not have the faintest idea as to how finding the upperbounds/lowerbounds. I have studied functions in the past but haven't ever ventured this deep in set theory.

Comment: If you work out some early terms or sketch a lot of the values on a graph then you might be able to guess as to whether the limits are achieved early in the sequence or whether they are not achieved because the sequence is always growing slightly over time. It's much easier to prove something if you know what the answer looks like

Comment: Also consider for which $n$ do we have $n+1$ being even or odd? What about $\frac12n(n+1)$?

Comment: I tried out more early terms and A assumes as greatest values 5 and -11/2 which match the graph I saw earlier. If n odd n+1 even and the second exponend 1/2(n(n+1)) represents the sum of all positive n. I can't see how this would allow me to reach a more rigorous solution. I tried to simplify the expression by pulling out (-1)^(n+1) but this does not allow me to simplify the expression, eventually. At the moment the most meaningful result I have is -11/2<A<5.

Comment: The point is that you can split your terms up based on the signs of the various $(-1)^\cdots$, that greatly simplifies the problem -- you have do do the same thing 4 times but each time is much easier than doing the whole thing at once.

Comment: I tried to split the terms. Since -1*-1^n=+/-1 for n odd/even (sorry, I reckon this is displayed awfully). 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-1)%5E(n)*-1*(2%2B((-1)%5E((n)%2F2)*(2%2B3%2Fn). 
Now I'm stuck.

Comment: For $n=1,2,3,4,5,\dots$, we have $n+1=$even,odd,even,odd,$\dots$. We also have $\frac12n(n+1)=$odd,odd,even,even,odd,odd,even,even,$\dots$. Combining these we have (even,odd),(odd,odd),(even,even),(odd,even),$\dots$. Do you see the pattern? Do you see how you can partition your set into a disjoint union of four sets such that each one has a representation as the set of terms of a series with an nth-term formula that doesn't involve powers of -1?

Comment: yes, I can! I drew a four lines system where, for each of the four patterns, the expression can be simplified to 1 fraction. Tomorrow morning I'll find to which values the terms of the series converge, if it does. Thank you until now, it's less foggy.